# Accessing HttpRuntime.Cache from other Thread

Tags: c#, caching, httpruntime.cache, httpruntime

I have a thread running behind my ASP.Net. In this thread I put data in the cache like this:

```
HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("test", "test", null, DateTime.Today.AddHours(6), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
```

On the other thread(the webpage) I first check if the cache contains any data, and then try to get the object from the cache, like this:

```
 if (HttpRuntime.Cache.Count > 0) {
          var test = (string)HttpRuntime.Cache["test"];
 }
```

**Edit:** Everytime when I'm trying to do `var test = (string)HttpRuntime.Cache["test"];`the cache will go empty(or will delete the object, haven't tested multiple objects in cache) plus the `var test` is also null. This is ofcourse when HttpRuntime.Cache.Count is bigger than 0

Oh and it gives no exceptions or anything

Comment: Could you clarify "after this line?"  Are you saying that in your if statement `Cache.Count > 0`, but sometime during `var test = (string)HttpRuntime.Cache["test"];` it is empty?

Comment: Everytime when I'm trying to do `var test = (string)HttpRuntime.Cache["test"];` the cache will go empty(or will delete the object, haven't tested that yet) plus the `var test` is also  null. This is ofcourse when `HttpRuntime.Cache.Count` is bigger than 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a potential inconsistent in your code that **DateTime.Today.AddHours(6)** that will not work. you should use **DateTime.Now.AddHours(6)**

DateTime.Today is current day starting `12:00 AM` , if you code runs after `6:00 AM` obviously the httpruntime cache isn't available.

Answer (score 1):

The Cache object in .NET is thread safe, so get data by thread is not necessary. You can view this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx.

adjust your duration: `DateTime.Now.AddHours(6)`